# Syntax Error within Linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create a Linq-Extension to distinct and filter my `User` objects within one method:

```
public static List<User> FilterDistinct<TKey>(this IEnumerable<User> source, Func<User, TKey> key)
{
    return source.Where(x => key(x) != null && key(x).ToString() != string.Empty).Select(x => key(x)).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

The call should look like `userList.FilterDistinct(x => x.LastName)`

But there is still a Syntax error within my code I can't figure out.

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: what was the error saying

Comment: @un-lucky added

Comment: So, the question is, are you trying to return a distinct list of `LastName` only, or a distinct list of `User` objects by last name?

Comment: you're selecting a property from type User and than calling a Distinct and ToList on an ienumerable of those properties

Comment: You could take a look at morelinq, which already has a DistinctBy method : https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to edit return value of your method.

```
public static List<TKey> FilterDistinct<TKey>(this IEnumerable<User> source, Func<User, TKey> key)
{
    return source.Where(x => key(x) != null && key(x).ToString() != string.Empty).Select(x => key(x)).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Comment: This won't return list of `User`s, as it stated in question.

Comment: This answer is clearly wrong, as it will return a list of keys, not `User` objects.

Comment: For me is not clear, why this method should return ```User``` object? I don't see any requirements regarding this. If user want to get ```User``` list as output, he able to call ```userList.FilterDistinct(x => x)``` and get what expected.

Comment: @tym32167: `(x => x)` - how this will filter source sequence?

Comment: @Dennis this key selector (look at parameter name). Function filters all nulls keys from original source and get distinct of them.

Answer (score 3):

What is returned from your LINQ query will be of type `List<TKey>` - ie, you're using a `Func<User,TKey>` to `Select` from your original list.

However, on the body of the extension method you've said it will return a `List<User>`.

So, then the function you pass in is pulling just the `LastName` from your users and returning a distinct list of them. Your return is `List<string>` not `List<User>` as you probably expect.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, @tym32167's answer breaks desired behavior, since you need `List<User>` as output.

You need to build up custom `EqualityComparer<User>` to call `Distinct` on `User` objects. Something like this:

```
static class MyExtensions
{
    private class UserByKeyComparer<TKey> : EqualityComparer<User>
    {
        private readonly Func<User, TKey> keySelector;
        private readonly EqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer;

        public UserByKeyComparer(Func<User, TKey> keyFunc)
        {
            this.keySelector = keyFunc;
            this.keyComparer = EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
        }

        public override bool Equals(User x, User y)
        {
            return keyComparer.Equals(keySelector(x), keySelector(y));
        }

        public override int GetHashCode(User obj)
        {
            return keyComparer.GetHashCode(keySelector(obj));
        }
    }

    public static List<User> FilterDistinct<TKey>(this IEnumerable<User> source, Func<User, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        return source
            .Where(x => keySelector(x) != null && keySelector(x).ToString() != string.Empty)
            .Distinct(new UserByKeyComparer<TKey>(keySelector))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Another option is to use `GroupBy` (but I think, that it will be slower):

```
public static List<User> FilterDistinct<TKey>(this IEnumerable<User> source, Func<User, TKey> keySelector)
{
    return source
        .Where(x => keySelector(x) != null && keySelector(x).ToString() != string.Empty)
        .GroupBy(keySelector)
        .Select(g => g.First())
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I don't see in question any requirements regarding function return value type. Why you decided that this is desired behavior?

Comment: @tym32167: Because original function returns `List<User>` and it is named `FilterDisctinct` (the keyword is "filter"). Your function behaves differently - it returns list of anything, but it can't *filter* the source sequence because of projection. I suspect, that OP was happy to see code, that compiles, and that's why he voted up your answer, but he still doesn't realize, what result he will get. Your code solves one problem, and invents another one.

Comment: but he passing into function a Key (not filtering criteria), so I decided that the name of function is not matched to "what user wants". Based on this, Im assuming that he wants to get distinct (and not null) keys based on users (for example, distinct ages or lastnames). In that case my solution seems should do exactly what user wants. Just asking your opinion about it.

Comment: @tym32167: "I want to ... filter my User objects". This is citation. Maybe, OP will clarify what he wants - he will receive notifications about our comments. :)

Comment: yeach, "filter my User objects" - I understand this as "I want get filtered something from User collection". So, I think that the question can be interpreted differently. I understand your point and I would think same if function looks like ```Filter(this collection, func<T, bool> criteria)```